# Removing rows in dataset goes wrong

Tags: r, row, data-manipulation

I have the following dataset:

```
text <- c(1:13)
numbers <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
test <- data.frame(
    text =text,
    is.numeric.feature = numbers)

   text is.numeric.feature
1     1                  1
2     2                  1
...
13    13                 1
```

Now I want to remove all rows where the numeric feature == 0 (there are none here, but in other datasets there are)
When I use the following command, my complete dataset is empty, what did I do wrong?

```
test[-c(which(test$is.numeric.feature==0)),]
```

Comment: @Ksilem. What you need is `data[data$is.numeric.feature != 0,]`. The problem with your code is that `which` returns an `integer(0)` result, which leads to an empty data frame as output

Comment: thanks, if you add that as an answer, I'll accept it. That worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that `which(data$is.numeric.feature==0)` returns `integer(0)` when there are no zeros.

```
> Data[-integer(0),]
[1] text               is.numeric.feature
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

To overcome this, better work with logical vectors :

```
Data[Data$is.numeric.feature!=0,]
```

On a sidenote, the `c()` in your oneliner is redundant. `which` returns a vector anyway. And please, never ever give your dataframe or vectors a name that's also the name of a function. You will run into trouble at one point.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way of doing this.

```
data[!data$is.numeric.feature == 0, ]
```

Answer (score 0):

It goes wrong because the `which` statement returns integer(0), an empty integer vector. Indexing `-numeric(0)` is not interpreted as "dont omit anything" but as indexing `integer(0)` which means "index nothing". I think it should go right if there is at least one zero in your data.

But you don't need which anyway and the logical vector is fine. These both work:

```
data[data$is.numeric.feature!=0,]

subset(data,is.numeric.feature!=0)
```